# appending to python list gives KeyError

Tags: list, python-2.7

In the following python function, pathToStart is a list of 2d points, and action_used is a dictionary with 'keys' of 2d points and 'values' corresponding to actions for the 2d points.

```
def reconstruct_actions(pathToStart, action_used):   
    actions = []
    for ii in range(0,len(pathToStart)):      
        next_state = pathToStart[len(pathToStart)-ii-1]        
        actions.append(action_used[next_state])   
    print actions
```

However, the function does not compile. What is the bug?

Comment: We don't know. We have no clue what the traceback looks like.

Comment: The KeyError was that when ii=6, then next_state=pathToStart[7]<check for yourself> which is (0,0).SO when i search for (0,0) in the dictionary action_used, then there is an error. So let me rephrase my question why is a key of (0,0) incorrect for a dictionary in python?

Comment: It's a valid key, but you can't get the value for it if the dictionary doesn't have one.

Comment: That was indeed the case. thanks.